# API Requester Error using Postmaster

Tags: php, api

I am attempting to use: https://www.postmaster.io for all my biggest shipping needs on my website project. I downloaded the example php zip folder here: https://github.com/postmaster/postmaster-php I am having the following errors along with the current code I have.

Okay so first off, I have a form submitting to the processing page. This looks like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="/config/templates/checkout.php"> 
   <input type="text" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" />
   <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then my processing page looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) 
{
    require_once('../libraries/postMaster/Postmaster.php');
    Postmaster::setApiKey("/* API key */");

    $zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];

    echo $zip_code;

    $result = Postmaster_Rates::get(array(
        "from_zip" => "67124",
        "to_zip" => $zip_code,
        "weight" => 1.5,
        "carrier" => "fedex",
    ));

    var_dump($result);
}
```

It is getting to the point of `$result = Postmaster_Rates::get(array(...` of the code and throws the following error. I have a feeling something is not getting passed through like it should, although I couldn't find anything to support my thought.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidData_Error' with message 'APIError 1000: Authentication Failed' in /home/www//config/libraries/postMaster/Postmaster/ApiRequestor.php:63
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/www//config/libraries/postMaster/Postmaster/Rates.php(15): `Postmaster_ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/rates', Array)`
>   #1 /home/www/config/templates/checkout.php(19): `Postmaster_Rates::get(Array)`
>   #2 {main} thrown in /home/www//config/libraries/postMaster/Postmaster/ApiRequestor.php on line 63

(*I removed my main url from the above error code.*)

Anyone have any experience using this system that could help me out?

Comment: Anyone? Anyone at all?

Comment: Unfortunately Postmaster doesn't seem to document any of their error codes or failed-request responses, but the exception you're getting sure seem to be just what it states: the api key you're sending to Postmaster is being rejected. Double check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure. I've used [EasyPost](http://easypost.com) before, as I felt postmaster was tough to work with. Their PHP library looks more up to date as well - https://github.com/EasyPost/easypost-php

Otherwise, is your zip value fixed (it seems to be)? I also think the zip code value should be a GET rather than a POST on the processing page. Have you tried changing that?